# Excel VBA datatype agnostic match

Tags: vba, excel, match

I have an Excel sheet with a row as:

`1      |   _Total      |   0 C:`

I have formatted the cells as text (can be re-formatted to anything). Even then, if I have to use the Match function to match `1` in that row (doesn't matter if it is application.match or application.worksheetfunction.match) I get an error (Type Mismatch error)

```
disk_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(disk_name, my_range, 0)

#   disk_name : has to be a string, since I might need to match "_Total"

#   my_range : it is the row
```

If I do `match(CLng(disk_name), ....)` it'll work, but I do not want to use CLng as I'll have to match `"_Total"` at some point.

Is there a type ignorant Match function? or a way around this?

Edit: For now, I've created a temporary array with all the cells in the row formatted as string with CStr() and using the match function on the array. Will keep the question around for a better answer.

Edit2: Added code-

```
Function get_property_value(disk_name As String, property_name As String, Optional counter_info As Variant) As Variant
    Dim disk_col As Integer, property_row As Integer, last_row As Integer, last_col As Integer, all_devices As Variant, device_iter As Integer

    disk_col = -1
    property_row = -1

    last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    last_col = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' create array of all the cells in the row
    ReDim all_devices(1 To last_col - 1)
    For device_iter = 2 To last_col
        all_devices(device_iter - 1) = CStr(Cells(1, device_iter).Text)
    Next device_iter

    ' match the row and column 
    disk_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(disk_name, all_devices, 0) + 1
    property_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(property_name, Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(last_row, 1)), 0) + 1

    If disk_col <> -1 And property_row <> -1 Then
        get_property_value = Cells(property_row, disk_col).Value
    Else
        get_property_value = "Value not found."
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can't you just make disk_name a Variant?

Comment: Nope, still gives error.

Comment: Post more of your code, one line is not enough.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

Comment: If the data contained in your row contains mixed text/numeric, you're always going to get an error on matching `1` against `"1"` because they are not the same. Typecasting your arguments won't help, you need to convert the data in the row so that it is all string values.

Comment: You're going to want to use `Long` data type instead of integer, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data contained in your row contains mixed text/numeric, you're always going to get an error on matching `1` against `"1"` because they are not the same. You can test this using the `Match` function on a worksheet. If your data is string, and you enter `=Match(1,...` you'll get an error, and vice-versa if your data is numeric and you enter `=Match("1", ...` you'll get an error.

Typecasting your arguments won't help, because it's the values within the range -- not the `lookup_value` argument -- which is causing this, you need to convert the data in the row so that it is all string values. You've done this by coercing to an array, and matching against the array.

Alternatively, you can just do some boolean check.

First: `WorksheetFunction.Match` will fail if the match is not found and your function will not return properly. So you need to be using `Application.Match`.

Then, you'll need to declare `disk_col` and `property_row` as `Variant`, since `Match` can return an error value, which will raise a mismatch if you try to put that result into a `Long/Integer` variable.

This should get you started:

```
Function get_property_value(disk_name As Variant, property_name As String, Optional counter_info As Variant) As Variant
    Dim disk_col As Variant ' in case the value isn't found, you need to be able to contain the error.
    Dim property_row As Variant ' same as above ^^
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim last_col As Long
    Dim device_iter As Long
    Dim all_devices As Range
    Set all_devices = Rows(1)
    disk_col = -1
    property_row = -1

    If IsNumeric(disk_name) Then
        disk_col = Application.Match(CLng(disk_name), all_devices, 0) + 1
    Else
        disk_col = Application.Match(CStr(disk_name), all_devices, 0) + 1
    End If

    With ActiveSheet
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        last_col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    ... 

End Function
```